# Import Data into Excel from Access Table, Code to Open Table and Specific Columns

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to import data into Excel from an Access table. I am getting a syntax error This error comes up when I run the line: .Select [Time], [Tank], FROM "UnitOneRouting", WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable In the Access Table there are four columns (in order) Date, Time, Tank, Comments. I only want to import two columns, Time and Tank but in the order Tank, Time; and I want to import them based on a date that is given in the Excel sheet. Thanks

How can I rearrange the following section to open the table, select the columns (based on date) and import the data.

With rs ' open the recordset .Open "UnitOneRouting", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable ' filter rows based on date .Select [Time], [Tank], FROM "UnitOneRouting", WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable rs.Open , TargetRange End With

**CODE STARTS HERE**

```
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable()
Dim DBFullName As String
Dim TableName As String
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim RpDate As Range

DBFullName = "U:\Night Sup\Production Report 2003 New Ver 5-28-10_KA.mdb"
TableName = "UnitOneRouting"
Set TargetRange = Range("C5")
Set RpDate = Range("B2").Cells


Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ' open the database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
        "U:\Night Sup\Production Report 2003 New Ver 5-28-10_KA.mdb" & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
        .Open "UnitOneRouting", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
        ' filter rows based on date
        .Select [Time], [Tank],  FROM "UnitOneRouting", WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
        rs.Open , TargetRange
    End With
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editted: You have a lot of problems here:

```
With rs
    ' open the recordset
    .Open "UnitOneRouting", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    ' filter rows based on date
    .Select [Time], [Tank],  FROM "UnitOneRouting", WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    rs.Open , TargetRange
End With
```

When you open your recordset you should specify the SQL statement, not just a table. That is meaningless to ADO. Furthmore, your SQL statement is bad. There should be no comma after the last field in your `SELECT` clause and no comma after your table in your `FROM` clause and your table name should not have double quotes around it and... a few other things about encapsulating your strings properly in the embedded SQL statement itself. Try instead:

```
 With rs
    ' open the recordset
    ' filter rows based on date
    .Open "Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & " ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable


End With
TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: I get a run-time error: "Syntax error in FROM clause" on the line
.Open "Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & " ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

Comment: Add the following line above the rs.open statement: `debug.print "Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & " ORDER BY Tank, Time"` Check your Immediates window for the SQL that it spits out and try to run that in your Access Database directly. Is the table name correct? Does the SQL it spits out look ok?

Comment: Also, I added a new line to the bottom of the code to spit the results being held in the recordset into your TargetRange with `targetRange.CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: This is the output I get in the immediate window when I run the debug.print. Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] =  ORDER BY Tank, Time

Comment: It looks like it's not getting a DATE from your RpDate variable. First make sure you have a date in B2 of whatever sheet that is. Then change this `Set RpDate = Range("B2").Cells` to say which sheet to point to like `Set RpDate = Sheet1.Range("B2").Cells`. Then change the bit in your SQL that looks like `WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & "` to `WHERE [Date] = """ & RpDate.value & """` Then run it again and see if they date comes through in your SQL code, with quotes around it. If it comes through, then stick that SQL into your Access DB and see if it likes it.

Comment: This is the output I get in the immediate window when I run the debug.print. Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] =  ORDER BY Tank, Time
It looks OK. But I am still getting the same run-time error. Am I missing something fundamental in the code? I am really a baby in this and have had no formal training.

Comment: But it doesn't look ok. There is no actual date in the WHERE clause. It should be `...WHERE [Date]="SOME DATE FROM B2" ORDER BY...` Something is going on where range `RpDate` does not have a value.

Comment: I'm sorry I sent that comment before I saw your latest answer. The date shows up now. This is the display I get from the immediate window. Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = "11/23/2012" ORDER BY Tank, Time
I am still getting the run-time error: "Syntax error in FROM clause." I am trying to retrieve from an Access table. I am not sure how to run the SQL immediate in the Access Database directly.